# Qu'est-ce qu'une interrogation indirecte ?

Tags: grammaire, terminologie

Dans les phrases suivantes:

- *Ce document indique qui est responsable du projet.*
- *Ce document montre comment mettre en marche l'appareil.*

Est-ce que les propositions: "qui est responsable du projet" et "comment mettre en marche l'appareil" sont des interrogations indirectes?

Comment: Pour ajouter une petite note : pour moi, le terme n'est pas trop utile quant à sa valeur syntaxique. Il sert peut-être à faciliter l'identification d'une question, mais au niveau syntaxique il n'y a pas de différence entre les phrases de ce type selon si elles contiennent ou pas un ou deux mots signifiant l'interrogation. Comme on l'a déjà dit, il s'agit d'une proposition subordonnée complétive : c'est tout ce qui compte du point de vue grammatical (si on l'oppose au point de vue sémantique). "Je sais qui", "Je demande qui", "Le document indique qui" ont essentiellement la même structure.

Answer (score 3):

Ces deux propositions sont de simples propositions complétives COD. Pour qu'il y ait interrogative indirecte il faudrait qu'il y ait interrogation.

**Interrogation directe :**

> Le directeur demande : « Qui est responsable du projet ? »

**Interrogation indirecte** :

> Le directeur a demandé qui était responsable du projet.

Comment: Merci.
Avez-vous des clés pour identifier une proposition interrogative indirecte? J'ai souvent du mal.
Par exemple: "Il ne sait pas comment lui annoncer la nouvelle." La proposiion "comment lui annoncer la nouvelle" est condidérée comme une interrogative indirecte.

Comment: Ces deux pages  : [1](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/la-phrase/linterrogation-indirecte), [2](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/2713.htm) devraient répondre à vos interrogations.

Comment: Si je ne me trompe les deux propositions données en exemple contiennent un pronom interrogatif et s'appellent propositions interrogatives indirectes dans la plupart les grammaires… De là à dire que ce n'est pas la même chose qu'une interrogation indirecte… hmm, mouais, je ne vois pas trop l'intéret.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je suis plus ou moins d'accord ... Un terme grammatical qui est aussi vague ne sert pas à beaucoup !

Answer (score 1):

Non, une interrogation indirecte traduit une question mais il n'y a pas de questions dans les deux phrases proposées, seulement des affirmations.